# Getting alert to pop up

Tags: javascript, button, alert

This is the HTML Code

```
<p>
 filename:
<input type="text" id="finput">
<input type="button" value="upload" onclick:"uploadText()">
</p>
```

This is the javascript function I tried to write and call:

```
function uploadText(){
  var textinput= document.getElementById("finput");
  var userinput= textinput.value;
  alert ("you chose" + userinput);
  };
```

I'm not sure whats wrong. When I click the button, there is no response or alert. I am using codepen do write this code. Any insight into what I'm doing wrong?

here is a link to the codepen : 
https://codepen.io/sophiesucode/pen/qBEoOEV

Comment: try onClick (capitalize the "c") click

Comment: Case sensitivity is an aspect of javascript, not HTML (generally speaking)

Answer (score 1):

In html, you assign with an equal sign (=) and here you have a colon (:) in the assignment of the event handler.

Colons are used in CSS styles but not HTML. Change it to an equal sign and it works.

```
<input type="button" value="upload" onclick="uploadText()">
```